# Angular - mat-table render data

Tags: angular, angular9

I am using Angular 9, and I am trying to render a [Mat-Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

If I use hard-coded data, it works perfectly, however if I use data from my service the values do not display in the table.

For example, the below code loads the hard-coded `ELEMENT_DATA` into the table for the first second until the service data comes back.

[image]

Then when the service data comes back, it just displays a list of empty rows in the table.

[image]

This means that there is a problem loading the data coming back from the service.

```
   let resp: Observable<Approvals[]> = this.service.getApprovalList();
    resp.subscribe((approvals: Approvals[]) => {
      console.log(approvals);
      this.dataSource.data = approvals;
    });
```

The JSON data returned from the service:

```
[{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"}]
```

(if I copy this JSON into the hard-coded data, it displays correctly)

**Question**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, so that the live data does not display?

**approval-list.component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
    <!-- organisation Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="organisation">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Organisation </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.organisation}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

**approval-list.component.ts**

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  organisation: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {organisation: '1'},
  {organisation: '2'},
  {organisation: '3'}
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-approval-list',
  templateUrl: './approval-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./approval-list.component.css']
})
export class ApprovalListComponent implements OnInit {

  //ELEMENT_DATA: Approvals[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['organisation'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Approvals>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor(private service: ApprovalService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadApprovalData();
  }

  public loadApprovalData(): void {
    let resp: Observable<Approvals[]> = this.service.getApprovalList();
    resp.subscribe((approvals: Approvals[]) => {
      console.log(approvals);
      this.dataSource.data = approvals;
    });
  }

}
```

**approval.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApprovalService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getApprovalList() : Observable<any> {
    let tokenStr: string = 'Bearer '+sessionStorage.getItem('jwt');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", tokenStr);
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/approvals", {headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json'});
  }
}
```

**approvals.ts**

```
export interface Approvals {
    organisation: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try?

```
resp.subscribe((approvals: Approvals[]) => {
  console.log(approvals);
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(approvals);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still does not display

Comment: Is there anything in your console.log? Also, what if you initialize your ELEMENT_DATA: Approvals[] = [];

Comment: The console outputs the JSON displayed above, i.e. `[{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"},{"organisation":"xyz"}]`

Comment: If I initialise: `ELEMENT_DATA: Approvals[] = [];`, then it just displays blank until the service comes back and then it displays empty rows.

Comment: The problem is because in the service, I have:  `responseType: 'text' as 'json'`. When I remove that, it works.

Comment: Ah yes, cause you can't have a type there. So is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because in the service, I have: `responseType: 'text' as 'json'`. When I remove that, it works.

```
  public getApprovalList() : Observable<any> {
    let tokenStr: string = 'Bearer '+sessionStorage.getItem('jwt');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", tokenStr);
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/approvals", {headers});
  }
```